# How to calculate ODS metric for edge detection

Tags: metrics, evaluation, edge-detection

I' am working on edge detection in images and would like to evaluate the performance of the algorithm using the ODS metric, but I don't know how to calculate it. I used canny and Holistically-Nested Edge Detection methods but I don't know how to calculate the ODS they calculated in their paper.